# Set the UITableView frame according to Tapku calendar height

Tags: iphone, ios6, calendar

I have `Tapku calendar` on the screen and below it there is a `tableView` showing its events. The problem is that the height of the calendar is not static: for some months it has 5 and for some 6 rows according to number of days in it. So the problem is coming in setting the table view below the calendar; the calendar comes over the table view or there is an empty space. Can I set the frame of `tableView` dynamically according to the calendar `frame`? Currently, I have a static frame for the calendar and table view.

Below is calendar frame.

```
self.tkCalendar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 96, 320, 308);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like below...

```
 - (void) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)monthView monthDidChange:(NSDate*)month {

[tableview setHidden:YES];
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
    [tableview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, calendar.frame.origin.y + calendar.frame.size.height, 320, 568 - calendar.frame.size.height - calendar.frame.origin.y)];
}
else {
    [tableview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, calendar.frame.origin.y + calendar.frame.size.height, 320, 480 - calendar.frame.size.height - calendar.frame.origin.y)];

}
[tableview reloadData];

}
```

let me know it is working or not!!!!

Happy Coding!!!!!

Comment: it is overlapping the calendar, i need below the calendar where calendar ends table should begin from there.